# Laravel 5 - new Route::resource followed the previous one

Tags: php, laravel-5.7

I just started with Laravel on my project and I face some problems in routes. Currently, I made tutorial resource route:

```
Route::resource('/tutorials', 'TutorialsController')->parameters(['tutorial' => 'id']);
```

`route:list` gives me the following output:

```
POST      | tutorials                
GET|HEAD  | tutorials                
GET|HEAD  | tutorials/create         
DELETE    | tutorials/{tutorial}     
PUT|PATCH | tutorials/{tutorial}     
GET|HEAD  | tutorials/{tutorial}     
GET|HEAD  | tutorials/{tutorial}/edit
```

Everythings works perfectly, now I would like to add some mini-series to some tutorials, I would like to add a new resource route and leave my route like this:

```
// Tutorials
POST      | tutorials                             
GET|HEAD  | tutorials                             
GET|HEAD  | tutorials/create                      
DELETE    | tutorials/{tutorial}                  
PUT|PATCH | tutorials/{tutorial}                  
GET|HEAD  | tutorials/{tutorial}                  
GET|HEAD  | tutorials/{tutorial}/edit             

// Mini-series of tutorials
POST      | tutorials/{tutorial}               
GET|HEAD  | tutorials/{tutorial}/create        
GET|HEAD  | tutorials/{tutorial}/{mini-serie}     
DELETE    | tutorials/{tutorial}/{mini-serie}     
PUT|PATCH | tutorials/{tutorial}/{mini-serie}     
GET|HEAD  | tutorials/{tutorial}/{mini-serie}/edit
```

At this point I was able to make it creating all routes manually:

```
// Mini-series routes:
Route::post('tutorials/{tutorial}', 'SeriesController@store')->name('serie.store');
Route::get('tutorials/{tutorial}/create', 'SeriesController@create')->name('serie.create');
Route::get('tutorials/{tutorial}/{mini-serie}', 'SeriesController@show')->name('serie.show');
Route::delete('tutorials/{tutorial}/{mini-serie}', 'SeriesController@destroy')->name('serie.destroy');
Route::patch('tutorials/{tutorial}/{mini-serie}', 'SeriesController@update')->name('serie.update');
Route::get('tutorials/{tutorial}/{mini-serie}/edit', 'SeriesController@edit')->name('serie.edit');

// Tutorials routes:
Route::resource('/tutorials', 'TutorialsController')->parameters(['tutorial' => 'id']);
```

As you may notice there is a lot of code here, I would like to ask if someone know if there is some additional option that would simplify this code. I would like to add a second `Route::resource` and leave it clean, but when I give it a try I got the following output:

```
// Route::resource('/tutorials/{tutorial}', 'SeriesController')->parameters(['tutorial' => 'id']);
POST      | tutorials/{tutorial}                  
GET|HEAD  | tutorials/{tutorial}                  
GET|HEAD  | tutorials/{tutorial}/create           
GET|HEAD  | tutorials/{tutorial}/{{tutorial}}     
DELETE    | tutorials/{tutorial}/{{tutorial}}     
PUT|PATCH | tutorials/{tutorial}/{{tutorial}}     
GET|HEAD  | tutorials/{tutorial}/{{tutorial}}/edit
```

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding to use route resource, the controller must be created as resource controller as well. In my case

```
   Route::resource('staff/regulatory', 'Regulatory\LicensingController',[
        'names' => 
        [
             'index'    => 'staff.approval.index', 
             'show'     => 'staff.approval.show', 
             'store'    => 'staff.approval.store',   

        ]
]);
```

This is how i use route resource. If you create manually then it has to be as how you did above. Try looking at route groups as well. Correct me if i am wrong TQ

Comment: You can use except() or only() to manage basic resource methods inside the controller, you can also add new methods but you will have to create a new route to have access to it. Unfortunately, your answer does not answer my question.